# SQL like group by and sum for text files in command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, awk

I have huge text files with two fields, the first is a string the second is an integer. The files are sorted by the first field. What I'd like to get in the output is one line per unique string and the sum of the numbers for the identical strings. Some strings appear only once while other appear multiple times.
E.g. Given the sample data below, for the string glehnia I'd like to get 10+22=32 in the result.

Any suggestions how to do this either with gnuwin32 command line tools or in linux shell?

Thanks!

glehnia 10
glehnia 22
glehniae    343
glehnii 923
glei    1171
glei    2283
glei    3466
gleib   914
gleiber 652
gleiberg    495
gleiberg    709

Comment: Duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10286522/424651 with similar answers, but the [top-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10286592/424651) there is more concise than the accepted answer below (both are awk programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AWK, you could do something like this:

```
awk '($1 == last) || (last == "") {sum += $2}
     ($1 != last) && (last != "") {print last " " sum; sum = $2}
                                  {last = $1}
     END                          {print last " " sum}' huge_text_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had to tweak a little to use TAB as delimiters but it got me the kickstart!

Comment: @dnkb: Using a comma in your print statements allows you to set the output field separator and then print will use it automatically. This may be what you did: `awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} ($1 == last || last == "") {sum += $2} ($1 != last && last != "") {print last, sum; sum = $2} {last = $1} END {print last, sum}' huge_text_file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This type of queries are most easily and flexibly done in SQL. You can use [SQLet](http://www.sqlet.com/) and SQLite for that purpose:

```
sqlet.py -d' ' -A file1.txt 'select a1, sum(a2) from A group by a1' | sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could a use a few lines of [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) to acheive this. Lua is available on a wide range of platforms including Windows and Linux.

```
-- Quick and dirty - no error checking, unsorted output

io.input('huge_text_file.txt')

results = {}

for line in io.lines() do
    for text, number in string.gmatch(line, '(%w+)%s+(%d+)') do
        results[text] = (results[text] or 0) + number
    end
end

for text, number in pairs(results) do
    print(text, number)
end
```

You can sort the output using any sort utility or a few more lines of Lua.